# Generics in Java, Merge method

Tags: java, generics

I have to create a Merge method to merge together two lists (Array-Based Lists). My method works, but now I have to change my method to generics. This is my method without generics, and it works. But I have having troubling converting it to generics.

```
public OrderedArrayList merge(OrderedArrayList list2){
        OrderedArrayList result = new OrderedArrayList(length + list2.length);
        int list1Index = 0;
        int list2Index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.maxSize; i++) {
            if (list1Index == list.length) {
                result.insert(list2.list[list2Index]);
                list2Index++;
            } else if (list2Index == list2.length) {
                result.insert(list[list1Index]);
                list1Index++;
            } else if (list[list1Index] < list2.list[list2Index]) {
                result.insert(list[list1Index]);
                list1Index++;
            } else {
                result.insert(list2.list[list2Index]);
                list2Index++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is my attempt at converted the above message to generics.

```
public  <T extends Comparable<T> > OrderedArrayList1<T> merge(OrderedArrayList1<T> list2){
        OrderedArrayList1 result = new OrderedArrayList1(length + list2.length);
        int list1Index = 0;
        int list2Index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.maxSize; i++) {
          T temp = list[list1Index];
          T temp1 = list[list2Index];
            if (temp.compareTo(temp1) == 0) {
                result.insert(list2.list[list2Index]);
                list2Index++;
            } else if (temp1.compareTo(temp)==0) {
                result.insert(list[list1Index]);
                list1Index++;
            } else if (temp.compareTo(temp1) < 0) {
                result.insert(list[list1Index]);
                list1Index++;
            } else {
                result.insert(list2.list[list2Index]);
                list2Index++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

There are many errors, and it is not complying or working. This is one of the errors that I keep getting:
Error: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to T

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use raw types in your generic version.

Comment: Please give the declaration of your `OrderedArrayList1` class - specifically, what type variables are declared at class level.

Comment: Note: you don't need to keep evaluating `temp.compareTo(temp1)` - store the result in a variable, and use that. Also, the comparison *should* be anti--symmetrical, so `temp.compareTo(temp1)` should be the same as `temp1.compareTo(temp)`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have declared `<T extends Comparable<T> >` at the class level, remove it on the method:

```
class OrderedArrayList1<T extends Comparable<T> > {
  public OrderedArrayList1<T> merge(OrderedArrayList1<T> list2) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Otherwise, you're defining a different type variable which just happens to have the same name, hence the slightly cryptic "T cannot be converted to T" message.